# how to get value of function if return type is class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new in c# and I am using trying to calling SOAP web service. One of functions in webservice is returning a class type. I am not able to get how I will return the value to type class.

My function: `AuthenticateUser(string user_name, string password);` is returning  class `EQUser`.

The class consists of the variables:

- user_id int
- user_name string
- level int
- user_group_id int
- password string
- extended_permissions int
- email_id string
- email_username string
- guid string

How do I typecast `AuthenticateUser` function to get these above values?

I have tried

```
ServiceReference1.EqClient user = new ServiceReference1.EqClient();
ServiceReference1.EQUsers equsr = new ServiceReference1.EQUsers();
user.EQAuthenticateUser("admin", "");
```

How can I typecast `user.EQAuthenticateUser("admin", "");` to `ServiceReference1.EQUsers` class?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you tried? Does it work or not? If not, how would we reproduce this issue?

Comment: nothing wrong with the code just i am not understanding how i will retrieve class values using  user.EQAuthenticateUser("admin", ""); function. Beuause this function return type is class EQUser

Comment: A webservicde doesn't normally return a class.  It return json string that has to be deserialized to a class.

Comment: @jdweng Or XML/SOAP/any other possible format. The point is Rajesh, we can't know. You didn't provide any information to us.

Comment: @patric what information is required, Because as i told that class is defined whit the following variables user_id int
user_name string level int
user_group_id int password string extended_permissions int email_id string email_username string
guid string

Comment: You need to convert the text response to the class.

Comment: @jdweng Doesn't the service client generation (`ServiceReference1`) do that?

Comment: I doubt it since the code is creating a new class object (calling the constructor) and not passing as data to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You [assign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator) the result of `EQAuthenticateUser` to a variable using the assignment operator `=`. In your example this would look something like:

```
ServiceReference1.EQUsers equsr = user.EQAuthenticateUser("admin", "");
```

Comment: it is showing cannot implicitly convert class error

Comment: Oh, I missed the distinction between EQUser**s** and EQUser. The short answer is, unless there is an inheritance relationship between the two, you can't. You have to write code to create a new instance of the type whose values are assigned to the values of the retrieved result.